# Does $\kappa = |T \times \frac{dT}{ds}|$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, physics, curves

If $T$ is the unit tangent vector and $\kappa$ the curvature, is it true that $$\kappa = |T \times \frac{dT}{ds}|$$?

I believe this is true (proof below), but am surprised that I cannot find it anywhere (only the seemingly more complicated formula $\kappa = \frac{|v \times a|}{|v|^3}$).

**Proof:** $$T' := \frac {dT}{ds} \\
N := \frac {T'} \kappa \\
|T \times N| = 1 \\
|T \times T'| = |T \times \kappa N| = \kappa |T \times N| = \kappa.$$

Comment: this is true if $s$ is the arclength of the curve. In general, the formula you mentioned is the one which applies

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo Yes, by definition $s$ is the arclength of the curve.

Comment: Then yeah you're correct. You can find all of these formulas in any good differential geometry book, like _The differential geometry of curves and surfaces_, by Manfredo do Carmo

Comment: The more complicated formula is useful precisely when you do not have an arclength parametrization. Your formula for arclength parametrization is rather silly: The definition of curvature is $\kappa = |dT/ds|$. The point is that $T$ and $dT/ds$ are orthogonal and $T$ is a unit vector, so $|T\times dT/ds| = |dT/ds|$ immediately.